# Creating and appending blocks of data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, json, mediawiki-api

I'm creating a web app that queries 10 wikipedia entries using the mediapedia API and displays each of them in blocks.

Here's the json:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=Shakira&limit=10&profile=fuzzy

What I want to do is display these entries all in blocks one below each other. 
So I was thinking of using a `for loop` to iterate through each entry and then using jQuery to append each block layered from top to bottom. How would I accomplish this?

Here's my codepen for simplicity:
http://codepen.io/tadm123/pen/oBqwYZ

My attempt to iterate and append entries to blocks:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    title = a[1][i];
    descr = a[2][i];
    link =a[3][i];

    var b = $('<a href = "' + link '"><div class="panel panel-info"><p class="panel-heading">' + title + '</p><p class="panel-body">' + descr + '</p></div></a>');

    $('#block').append(b);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems to work, except you're missing the `+` after `link` in `var b`. And `b` can just be a normal variable - no need to wrap it in jQuery.

```js
$.getJSON("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=Shakira&limit=10&profile=fuzzy", function(a) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var title = a[1][i],
      descr = a[2][i],
      link = a[3][i],
      b = '<a href = "' + link + '"><div class="panel panel-info"><p class="panel-heading">' + title + '</p><p class="panel-body">' + descr + '</p></div></a>';

    $('#block').append(b);
  }

});
```

```css
.form {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.panel {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius:
}

.panel-heading {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-body {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
  <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></button>
</div>


<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over array with forEach:

```
a.forEach(function(row){
    title= row[1];
    descr = row[2];
    link =row[3];

    var b = $('<a href = "' + link +'"><div class="panel panel-info"><p class="panel-heading">' + title + '</p><p class="panel-body">' + descr + '</p></div></a>');

    $('#block').append(b);
});
```